# Mobile support for UI for ASP.NET Ajax Q3 2010

Tags: telerik

I am using RAD controls for ASP.NET Ajax Q3 2010 extensively in a web site and now i have a request to modify this web site to cater for mobile(smart phones). 
I tried by putting viewport meta tag but the web pages are not responsive.
 Following are some of the RAD controls used in web site

RadTabStrip
 RadGrid
 RadMultiPage
 RadPageView

I would like to know what is the best way to redesign the existing telerik RAD controls based web site to serve on mobile as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade to the latest and greatest Q2 2014 release, where the controls offer [mobile and responsive capabilities](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mobile-support-and-responsiveness.html). You can use the new [PageLayout control](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/page-layout-overview.html) to make the contents of your web pages responsive.

There is also a [responsive web design sample app](http://demos.telerik.com/responsive-web-design-aspnet/), which could be helpful for your scenario.

We are currently working on the mobile version of RadGrid which will become adaptive in the Q3 2014 release scheduled for the end of October.